# How to allow for a user to enable push notifications after blocking?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification

I site I am working on asks the user (using firebase, js, and native chrome) if it is ok to send them push notifications. They may say no and click the little block button. Fine... that is great.

Is there a way I can provide them an easy button to be asked the same question again if they change their mind? Currently, Chrome asks if they want to allow or block. If the user indicates they want to block, but can a create a "Send me push notifications!" that re-requests this permission?

Answer (score 6):

Answer: No.

If user block permission via native request you can't do anything with that. But you can show them instruction how to unblock push by open settings. But you need to offer something very very valuable to a user. And expect low conversion.

The best way to subscribe users is to give them value before subscribe and require additional action. Example: show them HTML dialog with info about subscription and HTML buttons "Yes" and "No". When a user clicks "Yes" — show him a real request. If a user clicks "No" just close the dialog.
Later you can give more value to users who clicked "No".

You can find best practices [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WNPIS_2F0eyDm5SS2E6LZ_75tk6XtBSnR1xNjWJ_DPE/edit)